# JavaFX: ExecutorService.awaitTermination does not update UI through bound property

Tags: java, javafx

I have multiple tasks that run in a single thread. That works well and the corresponding tablecell progressbar gets updated as expected. Now before I execute them, I want to disable all buttons on the UI (that's my `enableControls` method). When the last task has run, I re-enable the buttons.

I tried the following, adding a shutdown and `awaitTermination` but then the UI does get not updated except when all is done.

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
   Thread t = new Thread(r);
   t.setDaemon(true); 
   return t ;
});

enableControls(false);
for (Segment seg : selectedItems) {
    Task loadingTask = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                updateProgress(i, 100);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    seg.progressBarProperty().bind(loadingTask.progressProperty());
    loadingTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> seg.progressBarProperty().unbind());
    loadingTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
        loadingTask.getException().printStackTrace();
        enableControls(true);
    });
    exec.submit(loadingTask);
}
exec.shutdown();
try {
    exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("test");
enableControls(true);
```

Alternatively I thought of determining if current task is last (no more seg in the loop) and reenable the UI controls in `setOnSucceeded`. Not elegant to state the least.

Any idea why the UI (through the bound value) is not updated - is this is a limitation of `awaitTermination` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is a blocking call, you shouldn't call that on the JavaFX application thread. Just create a new task to manage the task execution and await termination of your other tasks.  You can use a binding to your new task to disable parts of the UI while it is running.

[image: run]

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Waiter extends Application {

    private static final int N_TASKS = 3;
    private static final int TOTAL_TASK_EXECUTION_TIME_LIMIT_SECS = 20;

    private final VBox layout = new VBox(10);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button run = new Button("Run");
        run.setOnAction(this::work);

        layout.getChildren().add(run);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setPrefSize(100, 150);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void work(Event event) {
        Node controlNode = (Node) event.getSource();

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r, "load");
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });

        ExecutorService monitor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r, "monitor");
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });

        final List<LoadingTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < N_TASKS; j++) {
            LoadingTask loadingTask = new LoadingTask();
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
            progressBar.progressProperty().bind(loadingTask.progressProperty());
            layout.getChildren().add(progressBar);

            tasks.add(loadingTask);
        }

        Task<Void> taskRunner = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                tasks.forEach(exec::submit);
                exec.shutdown();
                boolean cleanShutdown = exec.awaitTermination(
                        TOTAL_TASK_EXECUTION_TIME_LIMIT_SECS,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS
                );
                if (!cleanShutdown) {
                    exec.shutdownNow();
                }

                Platform.runLater(() ->
                        layout.getChildren()
                                .removeIf(
                                        node -> node instanceof ProgressBar
                                )
                );

                return null;
            }
        };
        controlNode.disableProperty().bind(taskRunner.runningProperty());
        monitor.submit(taskRunner);
        monitor.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static class LoadingTask extends Task<Void> {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                if (isCancelled() || Thread.interrupted()) {
                    break;
                }
                updateProgress(i, 100);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> I need to disable all buttons and textfields on the stage

If you disable a parent node, it will recursively disable all children of the parent.  So disable everything in the scene, just bind the disableProperty of the scene root:

```
controlNode.getScene().getRoot()
    .disableProperty().bind(taskRunner.runningProperty());
```

The other way to disable input on a parent stage is to use a [WINDOW_MODAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#WINDOW_MODAL) or [APPLICATION_MODAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#APPLICATION_MODAL) dialog with an owner set.  For example a ControlsFX [ProgressDialog](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/ProgressDialog.html).

Comment: Perfect ! Works like a charm.One question I had was on your suggestion to bind to the runningProperty: this works fine if the calling button alone must be disabled but in my case, I need to disable all buttons and textfields on the stage. I could not find a way to group them all and use the disabledProperty. Instead I used a method to toggle all setDisable or setEditable before and after the tasks have run.